# ClickOnce windows application will not start

Tags: c#, clickonce, windows

I have created a windows application using c# VS express 2012. The app works great in the VS environment.  I have published the application using VS(ClickOnce) to the Desktop as an offline application, which does not check for updates. The app is not signed and security is disabled. The application seems to install fine when I run the setup.exe file.  However, when I try to run the program from the start menu nothing happens. In the task manager, a process for the application appears for a few seconds then just goes away. The app window doesn't show and there aren't any indications of an error.  If I navigate directly to the .exe of the app (%userprofile%\appdata\local\apps\2.0\%random id%......) and run it that way, it starts up and appears to function as designed.  I've done some research and found that certain drivers and software (if installed) will cause this behavior (i.e. Kensington Mouse driver and Provencia software(?)).  I've checked and I do not have either of these installed. Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Start Menu shortcut is just that, a shortcut.  If you right-click it, you should be able to select "Properties" from the menu and see both where it is actually pointing and what is used as the working directory.  I know the question is old now, but that is where I would start troubleshooting.